# How can I collect certain characters from a string seperated by new lines?

Tags: python, time

I have a list of time strings followed by phone numbers:-

```
00:12:23, 0712313412352

01:14:52, 0712312341256
```

What's the easiest way to get the time duration only?

```
duration = S[0:8] # duration is first 8 characters
```

Comment: if it's always exactly that format, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: duration = S[:8] is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all three parts of the time will always be formatted as two digits, meaning the entire time will always be exactly 8 characters long, then I think your way is easiest: `duration = S[:8]`.

Otherwise, if you know that your time will always be followed by a comma, you could split on the comma and take the first element: `duration = S.split(',')[0]`.

Otherwise you could use a regex if you don't know that your time will always be 8 characters long and you don't know that the time will be followed by a comma: `r'(\d\d?:\d\d?\d\d?)'`

Edit:

In your comment it says you want to read through all lines.  If you have a string containing all the lines separated by new lines, first you'll want to split the string into individual lines, by splitting on new line.  then you'll want to iterate through and get each time:

```
# Assume the text is stored in text_string
lines = text_string.split('\n')
times = [] # make an empty list to hold the times
for line in lines:
    time = line[:8]
    times.append(time) # Add the time to our list
print times # This will print our list of times
```

Comment: Just edited my comment to iterate through all the lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `lines.txt` contains your lines:

```
>>> [ x[:8] for x in open('lines.txt').readlines() ]
['00:12:23', '00:12:23', '00:12:23']
```

Or this, if the first field is variable length:

```
>>> [ x.split(',')[0] for x in open('lines.txt').readlines() ]
['00:12:23', '00:12:23', '00:12:23']
```

Answer (score 1):

one of the best ways is to use regex and create a useful pattern to find the needed string part

```
import re

string = "00:12:23, 0712313412352"
request = re.match(r"(^\d*....\d*)", string)
print request.group()
>>>00:12:23
```

you can try different regex pattern here on https://regex101.com/, you can also at python as interpreter